# Disk full when restoring Duplicity backup

Tags: ubuntu, backup, duplicity

I'm trying to restore a backup I made using Duplicity because my laptop got lost. I can't install Ubuntu into my current laptop, so I restore using Live USB. I can't restore the thing because duplicity keeps reporting that my disk is full. I created the live disk using Rufus with persistence enabled.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

try exporting TMPDIR env var pointing to a writable folder outside of your usb stick eg. on the harddrive. there is probably not enough space on that stick.

..ede/duply.net